# C# write multi lines to cs file

Tags: c#, file

I googled and found the solution at MSDN.

```
// Compose a string that consists of three lines.
string lines = "First line.\r\nSecond line.\r\nThird line.";

// Write the string to a file.
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
file.WriteLine(lines);

file.Close();
```

How to extend the **lines** to complex content which including some natural C# code lines. 
eg. I want to write the information below to my test.cs file.

Why?
 I am parsing a XML schema with C# Console Application. And i want to generate the Console Result to a .cs file during the compiler time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CommonDef
{
    public class CCODEData
    {
        public int iCodeId;
        public string sCode;
        public CODEDType cType;
        public int iOccures;
    }

    [Description("CodeType for XML schema.")]
    public enum CODEDType
    {
        cString = 1,
        cInt = 2,
        cBoolean = 3,
    }
```

thank you.

Comment: you want to read the cs file and write it into a file? or just write hardcoded code?

Comment: My practice:
Step1. I parsed a XML schema with C# Console Application. 
Step2. I want to write the Console Result to a .cs file at the compile time.(Building project).
Step3. The new .cs file can combined with my other .cs fils at the run time. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your source code is hardcoded as in your sample, you could use a C# literal string:

```
string lines = 
@"using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CommonDef
..."
```

Anyway in such cases it is a better idea (more readable and maintainable) to have the whole text contents into a text file as an embedded resource in your assembly, then read it using [GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx).

Comment: Some lines like using System, etc is hardcoded.
Some other lines like the content from the XSD file would be parsed by System.Xml.Schema automatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

(I'm assuming you're trying to build up the result programmatically - if you genuinely have hard-coded data, you could use Konamiman's approach; I agree that using an embedded resource file would be better than a huge verbatim string literal.)

In your case I would suggest not trying to build up the whole file into a single string. Instead, use `WriteLine` repeatedly:

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("foo.cs"))
{
    foreach (string usingDirective in usingDirectives)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("using {0};", usingDirective);
    }
    writer.WriteLine();
    writer.WriteLine("namespace {0}", targetNamespace);
    // etc
}
```

You may wish to write a helper type to allow simple indentation etc.

If these suggestions don't help, please give more details of your situation.

Comment: Thanks Jon.   
It's a good solution for me special for the part of XSD parser code. 
I will update the my code from Console.WriteLine() to Writer.WriteLine().

Answer (score 1):

I know an answer has already been accepted but why not use an XSLT applied to the XML instead? this would mean that you could easily generate c#, vb.net, .net without having to recompile the app.

Comment: I never learned XSLT before.  :-)   When i plan my project. i just think i should parse the XSD file with C# or Perl.   Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FileHandling
{
    class Class1
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter data");
            ConsoleKeyInfo k;
            //Console.WriteLine(k.KeyChar + ", " + k.Key + ", " + k.Modifiers );
            string str="";
            char ch;
            while (true)
            {
                k = Console.ReadKey();
                if ((k.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control) && (k.KeyChar == 23))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\b");
                    break;
                }
                if (k.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    str += "\n";
                }
                ch = Convert.ToChar(k.KeyChar);
                str += ch.ToString();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add some description / explanations on your code. As an answer containing only code is a low-quality answer